# Cant'have vs Could not

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

I am a bit confused as for what is the difference here:

> He could not be in the meeting, he is on a business trip.
>
> He can't have been in the meeting, he is on a business trip.

To me, both express an opinion about a past event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence:

> He could not be in the meeting

can be said *during* or *after* the meeting. "Sorry, Jim could not join us today" can be said while the meeting is taking place.

The second sentence:

> He can't have been in the meeting

can only be said *after* the meeting. The *can't have been* implies that the meeting has already taken place and that the speaker is refuting an assertion that he was at the meeting. Compare these two dialogues:

> Welcome, everyone, to the meeting.
>
> -- Where's Jim?
>
> Sorry, he **could not be** in the meeting today. He is on a business trip.

vs

> How was the meeting?
>
> -- It was great. Jim gave a presentation.
>
> He **can't have been** there, he's on a business trip!

The second phrase is a much stronger statement. The speaker is 100% certain that the following phrase could not have occurred. The first phrase is much more moderate and a simple statement of fact.